# Big O notation (exponential functions)

Tags: big-o

What is the big O notation of 2^(log(n!)+2) + 3^n
I can simplify it to <=2^(log(n!)) +3^n
And now I really don't know where to start or how to figure out the big O,
Because on the first term we have a smaller base but bigger exponent,on the other we have a bigger base but a smaller exponent

Comment: Not a programming question.

Comment: Try posting it to the [Math Stackexchange site](https://math.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer to this question is O(3^n), because the one with the bigger base will grow substantially faster (considering these are exponential functions) than the function with the smaller base.